# Cannot connect to MySQL db with nodejs (openshift app)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, openshift

I have a nodejs (with express) openshift app that has a MySQL database (because that is what I am most familiar with), and I cannot figure out how to connect to it on the local environment. My last project I used a php framework with mamp to connect to the local database. What is the equivalent for node? This is the code I have to connect:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');

 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '127.0.0.1',
  port     : '3307',
  database : 'test'
```

});

```
 connection.connect( function(err){
if (err){ 
    throw err;
}
else {
    console.log('Connected');
}
 });
```

Here is the error when trying to connect locally:

```
 Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:110:26)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:42:41)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:98:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/server.js:16:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

I am guessing that because I am trying to locally connect to the MySQL db set up by openshift, that I am receiving errors. I just dont know what else to try here. I have tried it without the password as well.

If I switch to localhost for the host, this is the error I receive:

```
Error: ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'stembuds'
at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:30:14)
at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:91:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:202:24)
at Parser.write (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
at Protocol.write (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:72:28)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:736:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:110:26)
at Protocol.handshake (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:42:41)
at Connection.connect (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:98:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/brandonmoffitt/stembudsnode/server.js:16:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Sorry for the length of this post, I just have no idea why it isnt working.

EDIT:

I  ssh'ed into the openshift shell to look at the mysql settings. When I do the 'show grants\g' command, this is what I receive:

```
  Grants for adminMYXaSuf@127.11.28.130

  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'adminMYXaSuf'@'127.11.28.130' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*D0CE5FA2AAD801A33C9190D0B615CC92F364BE6B' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

This password is different than the one openshift provided.

Comment: Are you sure the connection object is correct? From looking at the npm package 'pass' should be 'password'. Also make sure you have the correct port number, that defaults to 3306. Maybe you should also have a 'debug: true' and then show us the output of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are running this on your local computer?  If you want to connect to your mysql database on OpenShift from your local computer, you need to use the rhc port-forward command, and look at the port it gives you for mysql, so then you would set the ip to 127.0.0.1 and the port to something like 3307 or whatever it gives you locally.  Keep the port-forward command running while you test the connection. You could also try pushing your code up to openshift and run it with the values that you have (or use the mysql environment variables that you can get with env | grep MYSQL on your gear) and then see if it works.

127.x.x.x are not publicly available ip addresses, they are private to that server, that is why you can't connect to it from your machine, and need to use the rhc port-forward command

This works for me:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '127.0.0.1',
  port     : '3306',
  user     : 'admind4DxYD5',
  password : 'some_pass',
  database : 'developercorey'
 });

 connection.connect( function(err){
if (err){ 
    throw err;
}
else {
    console.log('Connected');
}
 });
```

Comment: Dude thanks! Yeah it gives me '127.0.0.1:3307' for the local connection to MySQL. Is the object way I am trying to connect the best way to do it? Also Locally, would I need the username and password still?

Comment: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED This is the error I receive when trying to connect with the new ip, and port number.

Comment: Are you still using the exact same code as above?  Don't forget to add the port: in your mysql configuration there of 3307

Comment: Yeah same exact code but now with the port #. This is the error I receive Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: also, I have this code, and I am just doing an npm start in the terminal to run it. This part is correct right? haha

Comment: updated my answer with a code example that works.  make sure you change your port and user/pass, and db name.  ssh to your gear and run env | grep MYSQL and make sure you are using the correct values also for dbname etc. i am running mine with node <name of file>

Comment: That works for you, in openshift? This code that I am using is at the top of my server.js file, outside the varSampleapp function. Furthermore when I go into mysql thru terminal with this command: mysql -h localhost -P 3307 -u adminMYXaSuf and then type in SHOW GRANTS\g I get : Grants for (at)localhost , GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost'. Why does it not recognize the username?

Comment: put that code in it's own file, and run it on your local machine with "node file.js" and see what it does.

Comment: I got it to work, it needed a socketpath:'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are going back and forth between running this on your machine, and running this on openshift's servers, and not telling us what errors you are getting where.

Answer (score 8):

did you read their doc?.
if you have load balancer, your mysql will install on another gear.
you need to use the env variable when you install the cartridge

```
port
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=44331

host
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=12345600a4382ec97a10000f7-somehost.rhcloud.com

OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=somerandompassword

username
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=yourusername
```

pass the variable when you start your app as args.

look at the example for node
https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/nodejs-example/blob/master/server.js

just use the env variable like process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST to replace the string in the database connection.

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');

 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST,
  user     : process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME,
  password : process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD,
  port     : process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT,
  database : process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME
 });
```

Comment: Thanks man. Where is this doc? Also, in the past I have had trouble using the openshift env variables in the local environment. And I am sort of new to JS. Could you elaborate on passing the variable as an argument? And when you say variable, you are talking about the env variable?

Comment: When I use the process env variables, this is the error I get Error: ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'stembuds'

Comment: what database your created?, the database is your app name, you can't connect with no database or wrong db name

Comment: I havent created a database locally yet. I am trying to do that through terminal but I cannot tell if I am connected to the correct mysql server

Comment: Props to openshift for making a workflow that is harder to use than the alternative...